# How can I remove filtered values from a Laravel collection within a for loop?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I would basically like to remove values from $collection to reduce the for loop duration since the filtered values are used only once.

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);

foreach ($collection as $k => $v) {
    $filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) {
        return $value > 2;
    })->values(); 

    // do stuff with $filtered

    break;
}
```

Results that I'd like to get:

```
$collection = [1, 2];
$filtered = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

What I'm getting currently:

```
$collection = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
$filtered = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
```

I've tried:

```
foreach ($collection as $k => $v) {
    $filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($collection) {
        $collection->forget($key);
        return $value > 2;
    })->values(); 
}
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can you tell what exactly you mean by "doesn't seem to work", like what error you are getting? or what unexpected results does the code give?

Comment: I showed the results that I'm currently getting in the sample code.

Comment: My bad, I misread the comments, usually people write them in separate code blocks to differentiate input from output, but makes sense now.

Comment: No problem. It's all good.

Comment: Running your code, I get ` Uncaught Error: Call to a member function filter() on array` Perhaps I am getting you wrong?

Comment: you can use another variable to push others

Comment: Are you using Laravel?

Comment: okay the updated code works

Comment: Awesome. That's good. :)

Comment: @SonuSindhu I did try that by using $collection->partition() but I need to update the actual $collection that the for loop is working off of to shorten the loop duration.

Comment: So, if I'm not getting the question wrong... You want to first get the filtered collection and perform some action on that filtered collection, once done, you want to get rid of the thos keys that you've worked on?
Actually I'm only curios about the loop. If it's going to break after first iteration why are you using loop? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
 
$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($value, $key) use ($collection) {
    if ($value > 2) {
        $collection->forget($key);
        return $value;
    }
});
```

Comment: It has a little bit different

Comment: Yeah, that's the right answer. You were just missing the condition for forgetting the key.